# Медленный секундомер java

Tags: java

Начал изучать java и сделал простой секундомер для android. Но когда запускаю идёт медленнее чем обычный (примерно в полтора раза). И при выключении телефона очень быстро идёт (секунд за 7 проходит минута). В чём может быть проблема?
Код:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.graphics.Color.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int seconds = 0;
    private boolean running = false;
    private TextView myTextView;
    private TextView myMillisecondsView;
    private Button startBtn;
    private Button pauseBtn;
    private Button stopBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_view);
        myMillisecondsView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.millisecondsView);
        startBtn = findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        pauseBtn = findViewById(R.id.pauseBtn);
        stopBtn = findViewById(R.id.stopBtn);
    }

    public void onClickStart(View view) {
        running = true;
        runTimer();
        startBtn.setClickable(false);
        startBtn.setBackgroundColor(LTGRAY);
        stopBtn.setClickable(true);
        stopBtn.setBackgroundColor(BLUE);
    }

    public void onClickStop(View view) {
        running = false;
        seconds = 0;
        stopBtn.setClickable(false);
        stopBtn.setBackgroundColor(LTGRAY);
        startBtn.setClickable(true);
        startBtn.setBackgroundColor(BLUE);
    }

    public void onClickPause(View view) {
        running = false;
        startBtn.setClickable(true);
        startBtn.setBackgroundColor(BLUE);
        stopBtn.setBackgroundColor(BLUE);
        stopBtn.setClickable(true);
    }
    private void runTimer() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int hours = (seconds/216000)%60;
                int minutes = (seconds/60000)%60;
                int secon = (seconds/100)%60;
                int mili = seconds%100;
                String myTime = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secon, mili);
                myTextView.setText(myTime);
                myMillisecondsView.setText(String.valueOf(seconds));
                if(running){
                    seconds++;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Нет абсолютно никакой гарантии, что ваш метод `run` будет вызываться какое-то определенное количество раз за секунду. В зависимости от загрузки системы, это может быть чаще или реже, что вы, собственно, и наблюдаете. Используйте [системную функцию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()), которая внутри использует более надежные механизмы для отсчета времени.

Comment: Для времени существует таймер. И использовать надо его